# Regex to find positive and negative match

Tags: regex, tcl

I am looking to match  a combination of positive and negative characters in regex (TCL).

Lets say I want to match lines that DO include 'def' and DO NOT include 'hij'.

```
ab def hhh    -> print
abdefxxhijzz  -> no print
hij           -> no print
123defhijxyz  -> no print
0def123hijxyz -> no print
```

I have tried :

```
{(def)(?!hij)}
{(def).*(?!hij)}
{.*(def).*(?!hij)}
{.*(def).*(?!hij).*}
```

All erroneously print '0def123hijxyz'.

On a cmd line I can do this with 2 x grep cmds.

```
echo 0def123hijxyz | grep def | grep -v hij
```

Could one of you experts kindly help with a regexp to achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Gert.

Comment: Negative regexes are always tricky, because "the absence of this string" isn't really a thing you can "find". Your best bet (which I don't know how to write in TCL) is the equivalent of `grep -v` - invert the whole filter, not the regex.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work:

```
(?!.*hij)(.*def.*)
```

It looks ahead for the substring `.*hij`, and if one can't be found, it matches `(.*def.*)`

Comment: This may need to be tailored, depending if the OP wants to match entire whole words or sub-strings.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you need to execute the negative lookahead first, and anchor it to make sure it's only applied once, at the beginning of the string.

```
{(?n)^(?!.*hij).*def.*}
```

- `(?n)` turns on `-line` mode, allowing `^` to match at the beginning of a line (what most regex flavors call `multiline` mode).
- `(?!.*hij)` searches the whole string for `hij`, and reports failure if it finds it.
- `.*def.*` consumes the whole string if it contains `def`.

The anchor is necessary to prevent it matching a string in which the unwanted word precedes the wanted one, like `hij def`.  Without the anchor it can find match by starting at the `i`.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of check, I would rather not use regexp and rather use string methods:

```
if {[string match *def* "0def123hijxyz"] && ![string match *hij* "0def123hijxyz"]} {
    puts "Match!"
}
```

`string match` uses glob matching, so that `*` is the wildcard.

`[string match *def* "0def123hijxyz"]` returns 1 if `def` is within the string, and 0 otherwise.

---

If you still insists on a regexp method, I would suggest this regex:

```
^(?!.*hij).*def
```

The `^` is a beginning of line anchor which causes the regexp to check the match only once and not repeatedly when the match fails (i.e. after it found that there is `hij` or there is no `def`).

Adding a `.*` in `(?!.*hij)` allows it to check the whole string, instead of a single position in the string.

`.*def` then attempts to match `def`. You don't have to use another `.*` at the end unless there's more you want to match, for example, `def` followed by `g` anywhere after it even if there are other characters in between would be `.*def.*g`. Using this `.*` at the end only gives more work to the regexp.

---

Some benchmarking...

```
% proc match {} {
        if {[string match *def* "0def123hijxyz"] && ![string match *hij* "0def12
3hijxyz"]} {
        }
}
% proc regmatch {} {
        if {[regexp -- {^(?!.*hij).*def} 0def123hijxyz]} {
        }
}
% puts [time match 100000]
0.49533 microseconds per iteration
% puts [time regmatch 100000]
1.38854 microseconds per iteration
% proc regmatcher {} {
        if {[regexp -- {(?n)^(?!.*hij).*def.*} 0def123hijxyz]} {
        }
}
% puts [time regmatcher 100000]
2.23913 microseconds per iteration
```

`regexp` takes 2-4 times longer than the simple string method.

Answer (score 1):

When testing this sort of thing, it helps to make a little tester procedure:

```
proc check {re} {
    foreach s {"ab def hhh" "abdefxxhijzz" "hij" "123defhijxyz" "0def123hijxyz"} {
        puts "$s => [regexp $re $s]"
    }
}
```

Let's check it out…

```
% check {(def)(?!hij)}
ab def hhh => 1
abdefxxhijzz => 1
hij => 0
123defhijxyz => 0
0def123hijxyz => 1
% check {.*(def).*(?!hij).*}
ab def hhh => 1
abdefxxhijzz => 1
hij => 0
123defhijxyz => 1
0def123hijxyz => 1
```

Great! We can now try out any RE we might think of against all our test cases. This is a *very* useful technique when writing your own REs and you've got a set of tests.

---

So… what might the RE that we need be? Well, we need a positive `def` and a negative `hij`, and that negative `hij` needs to apply *at every place in the string*. You have to think of it that way, because Tcl's negative lookahead constraints are always matched using non-greedy rules.

Let's cut to the chase. The RE you're looking for is `^(?!.*hij.*$).*def`.

```
% check {^(?!.*hij.*$).*def}
ab def hhh => 1
abdefxxhijzz => 0
hij => 0
123defhijxyz => 0
0def123hijxyz => 0
```

This works because we first demand that we match starting at the beginning of the string (Tcl's REs are unanchored by default). Then we put in a negative lookahead that says we mustn't match an `hij` somewhere between “here” (the start) and the end of the string; without the anchoring, this could also succeed by *not matching somewhere else* (automata-theoretic matchers are tricksy like that). The final part is a simple positive “find `def`”.

To see why anchoring matters, look at this very similar one.

```
% check {(?!^.*hij.*$).*def}
ab def hhh => 1
abdefxxhijzz => 1
hij => 0
123defhijxyz => 1
0def123hijxyz => 1
```

Why does that fail? Well, consider trying to start matching after the first letter; the negated lookahead always succeeds because that anchor fails.

You've also got to be careful with your test cases:

```
% check {def(?!.*hij)}
ab def hhh => 1
abdefxxhijzz => 0
hij => 0
123defhijxyz => 0
0def123hijxyz => 0
```

That looks nice and short, but fails with `abhijcdefxx`; the `hij` precedes the `def` and so doesn't cause a problem.

---

In general, if you were dealing with filtering a collection of lines, I'd recommend actually using:

```
# Read lines into list in $lines variable

# Positive filter
set linesWithDef [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $lines {def}]

# Negative filter
set linesWithoutHij [lsearch -all -inline -not -regexp $linesWithDef {hij}]
```

This is spiritually much more similar to that shell construction with piped `grep`s…

Answer (score 0):

I see this as two tasks, and I don't see regex as needed at all.

First search for strings that contain the required string ("def"), and then only if the string passes that first test, verify it does not contain the forbidden string ("hij").

Depending on which is more likely to eliminate the most possibilities, do that as the first step. For example, if it is more likely that many more strings will contain the forbidden string, do that check first, as your code will be more efficient.